# Array appending

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to add the user input from the text field to the array so that i can display those on the table view but unfortunately i am not getting the proper data into the array from the text field. I don't want to use two view controllers, I think it's possible to do it with one view controller with a tableview embedded as you can see in my code. I am new to Swift. How can i solve it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate ,  UITableViewDataSource{

var Dataceiver : [Data] = []
var todoItem: Data  = Data(tasksName: "")

@IBOutlet var taksTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var tasksTableview: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var taskButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    loadInitialData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadInitialData() {
    Dataceiver = [
        Data(tasksName: "Go to the dentist"),
        Data(tasksName: "Fetch groceries"),
        Data(tasksName: "Sleep")
    ]
}

@IBAction func tasksButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    self.todoItem = Data(tasksName: self.taksTextField.text!)
    self.Dataceiver.append(todoItem)

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Dataceiver.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let tempCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListPrototypeCell")! as UITableViewCell

let todoItem2 = Dataceiver[indexPath.row]

// Downcast from UILabel? to UILabel
let cell = tempCell.textLabel as UILabel!
cell.text = todoItem2.tasksName

//check if complete for the check mark
if (todoItem2.complete) {
    tempCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
} else {
    tempCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;
}

return tempCell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    let tappedItem = Dataceiver[indexPath.row] as Data
    tappedItem.complete = !tappedItem.complete

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}

}
```

Comment: put tableView.reloadData() after  self.Dataceiver.append(todoItem)

Comment: I have a working example of using a table view here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35588258/210171 Maybe it will help?

Comment: Worked thanks !! Could you explain me why ? i had to reload the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `tasksButtonTapped()` you need to reload table after     `self.Dataceiver.append(todoItem)`

```
@IBAction func tasksButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    self.todoItem = Data(tasksName: self.taksTextField.text!)
    self.Dataceiver.append(todoItem)
    self.tasksTableview.reloadData()

}
```

after adding values in array the table still has old values, you need to refres the table so that it can take new values which were added in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Call `tableView.reloadData()` after `loadInitialData()` to refresh the tableView.

Why you need to call reloadData() in UITableView:

> UITableView overrides the layoutSubviews method of UIView so that it
>   calls reloadData only when you create a new instance of UITableView or
>   when you assign a new data source. Reloading the table view clears
>   current state, including the current selection. However, if you
>   explicitly call reloadData, it clears this state and any subsequent
>   direct or indirect call to layoutSubviews does not trigger a reload.

Refer to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/)

Comment: it worked Could you explain me why ? i had to reload the date

Comment: Check the updated answer and accept the answer if it solved your question. :)